bash: make dir contained ":" or other special characters
I am trying to create a directory contained ":"
mkdir MD_6nax_apo_POPC:POPE_110A
mkdir: impossible de créer le répertoire «MD_6nax_apo_POPC:POPE_110A»: Argument invalide

While just mkdir MD_6nax_apo_POPCPOPE_110A works OK.
is it possible to fix the issue ?

Quote the dir name: mkdir 'some dir name with spaces and !@#$%^&*('

@0stone0, that's not required for :. Almost certainly the OP is trying to operate on a vfat or HFS filesystem, and both of those disallow : in names.

@JamesStarlight, ...so, it's possible to fix the issue, if you use an operating system that supports better filesystems; anything natively UNIXy (XFS, ZFS, ext3/4, btrfs, ...) won't have this problem.
